# Mifare Classic 1k UID no longer works after upgrading to Android 7 (SG Note 5)

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

We develop apps that use the Mifare Classic 1k UID, this works with all NFC Android phones that I'm aware of.

After upgrading to Android 7 with a Samsung Galaxy Note 5, the NFC no longer recognises the UID.  I've tested with multiple apps and cards, I can send/receive photos using Android Beam.  Other devices running Android 7 still work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does the Note 5 display any (error) message (maybe in a toast) about the card type being unsupported when you scan the MIFARE Classic card?

Comment: Yes, the tags are unsupported but the UID has always been readable.